# LLVM loop optimization bug?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, llvm, compiler-optimization

In my application I have the following Objective-C code:

```
-(void)layoutPages
{
    NSMutableArray* sections = [NSMutableArray array];
    [sections addObject:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world"]];

    for (NSAttributedString* contentSection in sections) {
        NSLog(@"%@",contentSection);
    }
}
```

[image]

Console output: `2014-04-22 14:11:01.505 MyApp[24784:830b] Hello world{}`

If I compile for x86_64 architecture using -Os optimization, LLVM then silently optimizes out the loop variable 'contentSection'. When I use -O0, the bug disappears.
This is the output when I try to print the description of the contentSection variable:

```
(lldb) po contentSection
error: Couldn't materialize struct: the variable 'contentSection' has no location, it may have been optimized out
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression
```

How is that possible? From my point of view a loop variable should never be optimized out when used inside the loop. I have seen that other people have a similar issue with LLVM but not with a loop variable. Could this be a compiler bug?

Comment: did you try using a property self.contentSections instead of an ivar

Comment: Thanks @PeterLapisu I tried this with the same result.

Comment: How have you declared the `iVar` or `@property`? As what might be happening is that more vigiours memory management might be taking place with `-Os` and `_contentSections` is getting deallocated.

Comment: @Lightforce and another option to try would be to pull out the `iVar` before the loop, `NSAttributedString *contentSections = _contentSections;` and then use that in the loop definition. And I've also just noticed that `_contentSections` shows in the variable stack so its probably nothing to do with my previous comment!

Comment: I tried both an iVar NSMutableArray* _contentSections as well as @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray* contentSections;
Anyway, since the property contains 10 objects when the debugger hits the breakpoint I don't believe it's related to the contentSections iVar / property.

Comment: What happens if you add a `NSLog` for `contentSection`?

Comment: @Lightforce yeah just noticed that - my bad there. Doubt pulling it out to a variable would help either! You could try using [`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:) too?

Comment: @Rich `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` produces the same issue. @Sulthan NSLog does indeed print the content of the attributed string. That is interesting.

Comment: @Lightforce what actually causes the crash then - which line in your posted code?

Comment: What's with const on contentSection (NSAttributedString *const)? Something does not look right there.

Comment: @lucianomarisi because you can't assign anything to the loop variable (well not so much you can't, it just won't mean anything)

Comment: @Rich Line 78 produces the crash. However if I comment out that line the application doesn't crash anymore but the 'contentSection' variable still has a nil value.

Comment: @Lightforce ah, then it might be the `NSAttributeString` you are creating! Try pulling that out to a variable (log it out) and then appending that. Either `[NSString stringWithCString:&formFeed encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` or `[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:...]` is returning `nil` - I don't think you can pass in `nil` to `appendAttributedString:`

Comment: @Rich the reason I asked is that I don't get that while reproducing the code, so I wondered if there was an underlining issue in that.
@ Lightforce can you show how you populate _contentSections?

Comment: @lucianomarisi Ok, I deleted some code and only left the bare minimum. I still have the same issue. I noticed that the self pointer is also const. Is that normal?

Comment: But the program no longer crashes now - I wouldn't worry about it, unless your issue is that the code you previously posted crashes? (I've still got that it crashes in your question btw)

Comment: Hmm, yes it doesn't crash anymore but I still don't understand why the optimizer behaves that way.

Comment: Its probably not the optimizer, its probably the LLVM debugger :)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a compiler settings issue. First you'll want to check that your run scheme is not in release mode. Go to "Edit scheme..." -> "Run" -> "Info" -> "Build Configuration". Make sure the value is set to "Debug".

If that is not the problem, then make sure your debug build settings don't have compiler optimization turned on. Make sure "Optimization Level" is set to "none" for debug. Also make sure there is no other place where the compiler optimization levels might be set, such as in the "Other C Flags" setting.